# Regex: Select anything in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using my custom button component like this -> `<h-button text primary outline>`. I want to write a regex that would let me select every button that has one or many props. I can easily select everything in the button tag using -> `<h-button(.*?)>` regex, but I don't know how to select only a specific word or two.

##### Example:

Let's say I have 3 buttons

```
<h-button text primary outline>
<h-button primary text outline>
<h-button text success outline>
```

And I want to find every button that has `text` and `primary` in it.

##### Expected result:

Regex should find these two buttons

```
<h-button text primary outline>
<h-button primary text outline>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<h-button .*?(text .*primary|primary .*text).*?>/
```

https://regex101.com/r/3POnQX/1

Comment: [Another visualisation](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%3Ch-button%20.*%3F(text%20.*primary%7Cprimary%20.*text).*%3F%3E)